# Aspect not being compile-time woven into target classes despite seemingly correct configuration

Tags: java, maven, aspectj

I have been successfully using Aspects with CTW for some time, although always for weaving code I link against, rather than code I compile.

In a [test project](https://github.com/BudWhiteStudying/aspect-logging), reusing the configurations that allowed me to make CTW work for external classes, I've been trying to weave code I compile, but had no success.

**I'd be grateful to anyone who could help me spot whatever it is that I'm doing wrong here.**

I tried both the [call](https://github.com/BudWhiteStudying/aspect-logging/tree/call) and the [execution](https://github.com/BudWhiteStudying/aspect-logging/tree/execution) approach, but to no avail.

The intended behavior is to intercept all method calls within the `com.budwhite.studying.aspect.logging.service` package, print a log message before their execution, and another log message after their execution.

I tried adding the `aspectj-report` goal to the `aspectj-maven-plugin` execution, and the generated documents *do say* that my `LoggingAspect` is advising the classes within that package - but in practice the aspect logic isn't executed when those methods are invoked - and I can't see any trace of the woven aspect code within the `.class` files.

All the configuration can be found in the GH repo I linked, but here are the main bits from the `execution` attempt (which is the approach I am successfully using in other projects, weaving code I link against):

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.budwhite.studying</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspect-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <logback.version>1.3.11</logback.version>
        <aspectj.version>1.8.13</aspectj.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                    <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
                    <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                    <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
                    <Xlint>ignore</Xlint>
                    <complianceLevel>${maven.compiler.source}</complianceLevel>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <sources>
                        <source>
                            <basedir>src/main/java</basedir>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/LoggingAspect.java</include>
                            </includes>
                        </source>
                    </sources>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- IMPORTANT -->
                        <phase>process-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>aspectj-report</goal>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>-XX:-UseSplitVerifier</argLine>
                    <argLine>
                        -javaagent:${user.home}/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar
                    </argLine>
                    <useSystemClassLoader>true</useSystemClassLoader>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**aop.xml**

```
<aspectj>
    <weaver options="-verbose -showWeaveInfo">
        <include within="**.LoggingAspect"/>
        <include within="com.budwhite.studying.aspect.logging.service..*"/>
    </weaver>
    <aspects>
        <!-- Aspects -->
        <aspect name="**.LoggingAspect"/>
    </aspects>
</aspectj>
```

**LoggingAspect.java**

```
package com.budwhite.studying.aspect.logging.aspect;


import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import static java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis;

@Aspect
public class LoggingAspect {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggingAspect.class);
    @Around("execution(* com.budwhite.studying.aspect.logging.service..*(..))")
    public Object whatever(ProceedingJoinPoint thisJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("EVEN IF I DID SOMETHING WRONG WITH SLF4J, THIS PRINTOUT SHOULD SHOW UP");
        logger.warn("{} begins, args are [{}]",
                thisJoinPoint.getSignature().getName(),
                Arrays.stream(thisJoinPoint.getArgs())
                        .map(Object::toString)
                        .collect(Collectors.joining(",")));
        long startTime = currentTimeMillis();
        Object result = thisJoinPoint.proceed();
        logger.warn("{} ends, execution time {} ms, output is {}",
                thisJoinPoint.getSignature().getName(),
                currentTimeMillis()-startTime,
                result!=null ? result : ""
                );
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: I strongly recommend to upgrade all the plugin versions you are using because those are ancient old...

Comment: @khmarbaise You’re absolutely right, and I did start with the latest version of everything; but out of desperation I subsequently downgraded all versions in order to match those of my legacy project that does work (to no avail).

Comment: Why would you need _aop.xml_ for compile-time weaving? That one is for load-time weaving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Over-configuration is the cause of your problem. Simply remove the `<sources/>` section, which limits the AspectJ compiler to only compile the aspect but not the remaining code it ought to be woven into. If you do that, your sample project immediately works.

Anyway, here is a somewhat more streamlined version of your POM, using the `dev.aspectj` plugin instead of the Mojohaus one (even though upgrading that one to 1.14.0 would also suffice for Java 8 or 11). As of today, the Mojohaus plugin still does not support Java 17+, while the AspectJ.dev one does.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.budwhite.studying</groupId>
  <artifactId>aspect-logging</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <logback.version>1.3.11</logback.version>
    <aspectj.version>1.9.20.1</aspectj.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
      <version>${logback.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
      <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
      <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.11.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
          <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>dev.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.13.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <complianceLevel>${maven.compiler.source}</complianceLevel>
          <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
          <Xlint>ignore</Xlint>
          <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>aspectj-report</goal>
              <goal>compile</goal>
              <goal>test-compile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Please also get rid of your *aop.xml*, because you are not using load-time weaving and also should not in your test, because with CTW that simply is not necessary.

P.S.: Here is a [pull request](https://github.com/BudWhiteStudying/aspect-logging/pull/1) for you. Sorry for reformatting the files to indentation with 2 instead of 4 spaces. My IDE does that. You can simply activate this option when [reviewing the diff](https://github.com/BudWhiteStudying/aspect-logging/pull/1/files?diff=unified&w=1):

[image: "Hide whitespace" option on GitHub]

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. Admittedly I had a very "empirical" understanding of AspectJ, so I just put together the configuration that somehow *worked* in my other project. Do you know of some sort of documentation page about the AJ project? All I could find was some Spring-related documentation, but I'd like to keep it Spring-agnostic, at least in general.

Comment: Have you tried your favourite web search engine to find out about AspectJ documentation directly on the AspectJ website? It is super easy to find, way quicker than asking a question here and waiting for a response. Just yesterday someone asked the same question on the [AspectJ users mailing list](https://www.eclipse.org/lists/aspectj-users/msg15572.html).

Comment: Matter of fact yes, I did try my favorite web search engine, but the "correct" AspectJ documentation website (which I now gathered from the mailing list link you shared) shows up at the 7th place, with no metadata on top of it, which is why I did not pick it up earlier. Anyway, thank you for sharing the link, now I know where to look.